# Match a pattern with iterator in loop

Tags: javascript

i have this loop in javascript which executes code every 3rd element in the loop, how could I do the same but with this pattern:

2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th etc

```
if ( index % 3 === 0 ) {
    // <p>message</p>
}
```

Comment: show your full code.

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking"? Ai ai ai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have does 0,3,6, just adjust the remainder. `2 % 3` and `5 % 3` return 2

```
if ( index % 3 === 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (index+2) % 3 === 0 ) {
    // <p>message</p>
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your change?

Comment: It adds 1 to the index and the checks for modulus 3 being equal to 0: this should return true for 2, 5, 8, 11, etc.  Though I like Juan's answer better so up-voted his, mine is another working alternative

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I believe  yours should say `if (index + 2) % 3 === 0`, otherwise, I think it's just as valid as mine.